# Unable to Create Live Smooth Streaming Publishing Point Programatically

Tags: rest, iis, live, smooth-streaming

I'm trying to use the [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh206008%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for IIS Media Services to create a Live Publishing point programatically. For this, I'm sending a POST call to this URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1/services/smoothstreaming/publishingpoints.isml/settings
```

I've included two custom headers to the request:

```
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Slug: /test.isml
```

And this is the body of the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <id>http://127.0.0.1/test.isml/settings</id>
    <title>Test</title>
    <updated>2012-07-12T19:13:25Z</updated>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <SmoothStreaming xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/iis/media/2011/03/streaming/management">
        <Settings>
          <Title>Test</Title>
          <SourceType>Push</SourceType>
          <AutoStart>false</AutoStart>
          <AutoRestartOnEncoderReconnect>false</AutoRestartOnEncoderReconnect>
          <LookAheadChunks>2</LookAheadChunks>
          <Archive enabled="false">
            <Path useEventIdOnPath="false" />
          </Archive>
          <ClientConnections enabled="true">
            <ClientManifestVersion>2.0</ClientManifestVersion>
          </ClientConnections>
          <ServerConnections enabled="false">
            <SendEndOfStreamOnStop>false</SendEndOfStreamOnStop>
          </ServerConnections>
        </Settings>
      </SmoothStreaming>
    </content>
  </entry>
```

IIS is giving me a 405/Bad Request error with this body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SmoothStreaming xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/iis/media/2011/03/streaming/management">
  <Error>
    <ErrorCode>0x80880026</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorMessage>The resource contains one or more elements that contain invalid data. For information about valid resource representations, please see the documentation for the supported schemas.</ErrorMessage>
  </Error>
</SmoothStreaming>
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ommiting the "Archive" and "ServerConnections" nodes fixed it. Not sure it there's anything wrong in them, or if they're only supposed to be included when enabled=true.